# Immutable.js: "Flatten" a nested collection of maps without flattening the maps

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a `bookshelf` API with methods to return sorted Immutable `List`s of `Maps` representing books.  In turn, these book `Maps` have methods to return sorted Immutable `Lists` of their chapters, and so on with the pages of each chapter.

I am trying to write a method that iterates over each nested list flattens their items, and joins the items together in a single-level list in their original order.  However, I can't use `flatten()` because it will corrupt the `Maps`.  This is what I've come up with, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

Does Immutable have something in its API that can achieve the following?

```
  let sortedCollection = List();
  bookshelf.getSortedBooks().forEach((book) => {
    sortedCollection = sortedCollection.push(book);
    bookshelf.getSortedChapters(book.getId()).forEach((chapter) => {
      sortedCollection = sortedCollection.push(chapter);
      bookshelf.getSortedPages(book.getId(), chapter.getId()).forEach((page) => {
        sortedCollection = sortedCollection.push(page);
      });
    });
  });
  return sortedCollection; // [book1, chapter1, page1, chapter2, page1, page2 ... book2]
```